# Magento2 - product collection filter out of stock products

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I could not find any relevant reference how to filter out products that are "Out of Stock" when dealing with product collection.
Here is the code sample:

```
<?php

$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection);

return $collection;
```

I have set "Display Out of Stock Products" to "No" but that has no affect on given code sample. Is there a common way (e.g. helper method) that can be used to filter out of stock products based on config value set?

Comment: did u find a solution to this?

Answer (score 10):

To bypass removing out of stock products in frontend (which could happens if you switched off showing out of stock items at stock options config page) we just need to set up a flag before we load the collection as

> $collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)

where $collection is instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection

Comment: The only solution that works for me on 2.1.9. Thx a lot

Comment: Cripes this was such a life saver when trying to remove old products we had disabled.

Answer (score 7):

Use below code to your class to filter out of stock product

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
 */
protected $_stockFilter;
```

on class constructor

```
 public function __construct(
    .....
     \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter
    .....
) {
     $this->_stockFilter = $stockFilter;
}
```

in your method add the following code

```
public function getProducts(){
..........
 $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
..........
}
```

here `$collection` is product collection.

Answer (score 6):

Use below code for filter out of stock product

```
protected $_linkFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $linkFactory
) {
    $this->_linkFactory = $linkFactory;
}
```

---

```
    $collection = $this->_linkFactory->create()
        ->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        )
    ;

    $collection->joinField(
        'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
    );
```

Comment: The Proper way to join cataloginventory_stock_status table. In you case you broken ability to not manage stock for product

Answer (score 6):

Use method for this `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock::addInStockFilterToCollection` like below.

Example:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection);
$this->stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Looking at M2 source https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Helper/Stock.php#L108-L132 I don't see how it could even do that as `$collection` parameter is not passed by reference nor returned by method.

Comment: @werd Objects in PHP are passed by reference as default

Comment: @Volvox no they are not :)

Comment: @werd: Volvox is right. Objects are indeed passed by reference by default, at least within the sense you're using it here. (Technically the implementation is different than with primitive references, but the effect is the same. They're not copied/passed by value, which is what lets `addInStockFilterToCollection` work.) http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 3):

There a couple of ways you can go about this. The first would be to use the stock helper `Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock`. This class contains the following two public methods:

```
addInStockFilterToCollection($collection)
```

&&

```
addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection)
```

***NOTE***

is that both of these methods check to see if the config setting for showing out of stock products is enabled.

These methods use the `addStockDataToCollection($collection, $isFilterInStock)` from the `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status` class.

Here the $isFilterInStock variable will either join the stock index table via a left join. Additionally, if this variable is set to true, a stock status filter is added using a where statement. For example:

```
   /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @param bool $isFilterInStock
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     */
    public function addStockDataToCollection($collection, $isFilterInStock)
    {
        $websiteId = $this->getStockConfiguration()->getDefaultScopeId();
        $joinCondition = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id' . ' AND stock_status_index.website_id = ?',
            $websiteId
        );

        $joinCondition .= $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            ' AND stock_status_index.stock_id = ?',
            Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID
        );
        $method = $isFilterInStock ? 'join' : 'joinLeft';
        $collection->getSelect()->$method(
            ['stock_status_index' => $this->getMainTable()],
            $joinCondition,
            ['is_salable' => 'stock_status']
        );

        if ($isFilterInStock) {
            $collection->getSelect()->where(
                'stock_status_index.stock_status = ?',
                Stock\Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK
            );
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

So to answer your question, use thew addStockDataToCollection method in the `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status` class and set the `$isFilterInStock` variable to true.

Answer (score 1):

> **Use below code for filter out of stock Simple/Config products** ***[magento 2 out of stock enabled configurable products]***

```
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');

$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create();

$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);

$collection =
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', ['stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'])
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 0])
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', ['eq' => 'configurable'])->load();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo 'Config Product SKU: '.$product->getSku()."\n\n";
}
```

> **Note:** Change **$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', ['eq' => 'configurable'])** as per your requirements.

> **MySQL Query as follows:**

SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`is_in_stock` AS `stock_status`, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` ON (cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id=e.entity_id)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 14) WHERE ((cataloginventory_stock_item.is_in_stock = 0) AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1') AND (`e`.`type_id` = 'configurable')) AND (e.created_in <= '1589313000') AND (e.updated_in > '1589313000') ORDER BY `e`.`created_at` DESC;