# Magento 2: Sorting out of stock items in catalog page

Tags: magento2, catalog

I need to display out of stock products after products, that is in stock.
Can anyone help me with this?

As you can see on this picature [image: this picture] not available and Out of  Stock products is showing after available products. How i can realize it in Magento 2?

Comment: Hi Please explain detail so, i can help you

Comment: @NikhilVaghela, i need to show out of stock products on product listing and search, but they must be after in stock products.

Comment: may be it will help 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122972/magento2-product-collection-filter-out-of-stock-products/122976

You need add two times query

Comment: @NikhilVaghela i'm uploaded screen with examle