# How to get Salable Quantity in product collection?

Tags: magento2.3, product-collection

Need to filter product collection by salable qty in frontend in catalog>product>list.phtml. Currently, I am processing the saleable qty inside foreach loop but it takes lot of resources and some time site getting down.

Here is my code

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft( ['sot' => 'inventory_reservation'], 'sot.sku = e.sku', 'quantity as inQty' );
```

Comment: $_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['sot' => 'inventory_reservation'],
    'sot.sku = e.sku',
    'quantity as inQty'
);

Comment: Please share your code in your question

Comment: @MohitPatel Here is my code.

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122976/85907 @Akhil Anand